# Does anyone know how to add popup window in sonata admin for create/add route?

Tags: symfony, popup, sonata-admin

Does anyone know how to add popup window in sonata admin for create/add route?

If I need to add more categories while creating an item, there should be a button "Add new" along with the category selection box, when i click on the "Add new" it should appear as a popup window to add the new category.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the documentation regarding which `types` provides sonata admin bundle :

The `sonata_type_collection` should do what you asked.

Ref : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html#advanced-usage-one-to-many